# Force simple_form to render 'help-block' span

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I'm trying to make [Simple Form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) to work with a Jquery Validation plugin, so we can validate some data, before it goes to back end.

It is working already, but I need the `<span class="help-block">` to be rendered, no matter if that was an error or not (seeing the simple_form source, I came to the code that says to render error span only if there was error, which is brought by the backend).

Does anyone knowns if there's a way to make `simple_form` render this `span` by default? I really didn't want to write this to every single input.

Comment: I think you are looking for showing hint (I have not used this ,  just read the doc in the link )
<%= f.hint 'No special characters, please!' %>

Comment: Maybe it is. But I would like to configure a wrapper to always use it, So I don't need to write on every field. My goal here is to have this span/div with help-block class, so the jquery validation lib can use it to show validation messages.